# Python pandas: reading and writing cells in a dataframe from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having some trouble working with pandas dataframes and it is becoming somewhat frustrating.

I am trying to reference/edit a very simple .csv file in a few python scripts I am working on. My goal is to read and edit the .csv file as needed to keep track of some basic values.

The .csv (called id_store) is created from a python dictionary, which for all intents and purposes looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_dest = 'id_store.csv'
idDict = {'first_id': [1,None], 'last_id': [10,None]}

pd.DataFrame(data=idDict, index=['old','new']).to_csv(csv_dest)
```

When I look at the .csv I created using excel, so far so good, but when I read from it in a different session things get weird:

```
test = pd.read_csv('id_store.csv')

test
      Unnamed: 0       first_id     recent_id
0        old           1            10
1        new           NaN          NaN
```

I have tried reading from test numerous ways but I can't seem to be able to access it properly. If possible I'd like to read from the (old, recent_id) cell, edit the (new, recent_id) cell then save the edited dataframe as a new instance of 'id_store.csv'. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=idDict, index=['old','new'])
df.index.name = 'LOL'
df.to_csv(csv_dest)
pd.read_csv('id_store.csv',index_col ='LOL')
Out[26]: 
     first_id  last_id
LOL
old       1.0     10.0
new       NaN      NaN
```

Lazy solution ...

```
df=pd.read_csv('id_store.csv',index_col ='Unnamed: 0')

df
Out[43]: 
     first_id  last_id
old       1.0     10.0
new       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Everything seems to work now that I have established this index column. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoshKraushaar Yw~ also , Cause I am lazy :), you can just try `df=pd.read_csv('id_store.csv',index_col ='Unnamed: 0')`

Comment: That is some impressive laziness, consider me in awe.

Comment: @JoshKraushaar but I will recommend keep a index name , at least make excel look better . :)